# Javadoc for JavaFX 2.x works partially in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc, code-completion, javafx-2

I've created a javafx project in netbeans. It compiles fine, code completion works...sort off.. instead of proper argument names, autocompleted functions look like: somefunction(arg1,arg2,arg3)...  any ideas how to fix this? During auto-completion Netbeans displays proper text descriptions of functions or classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug in Netbeans: [Netbeans Bugzilla Link](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=209623)